# JQuery KeyUp Live Search. How to?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to find out why is it that I can get my live search to work but it returns all results from mysql table no matter what I type. Perhaps you could help?

I am trying to get the previous request and initiate a new one on each keyup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Help Tool 2.0</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){



$('#search-box').keyup(function() {
$("#results").html('');
    var xhr;
    var keywords = $(this).val();
    if(xhr != null) xhr.abort();

    xhr = $.get("search.php", {q: keywords}, function() {
    //alert("success");
  })

  .success(function(data) { 
  xhr = null;

  //alert("second success");

  $("#results").html(data);

  })



});


});
</script>

<input id="search-box" name="q" type="text" />
<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php


include_once ('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['q'])){

$keyword = trim($_GET['q']) ;
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);

$query = "select topictitle,topicdescription from topics where topictitle like '%$q%' or topicdescription like '%$q%'";

//echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($result){

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     echo '<p> <b>'.$row['topictitle'].'</b> '.$row['topicdescription'].'</p>';
    }
    }else {
        echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['q'].'"';
    }

}
}else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}




?>
```

Comment: Try to fetch the actual SQL (print to log or response or something). It will probably point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 13):

Try this js code in place of what you have.  I added the delay function so that the script waits a specified amount of time after the user stops typing before sending the request.  This prevents a large amount of requests getting sent to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var delay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$("#search-box").keyup(
    function () {
        delay(function () {
            var keyword = $("#search-box").val();
            var URL = encodeURI("search.php?q=" + keyword);
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#results").html(response);
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    }
);
</script>
```