# OnKeyup search string and hide/show - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to filter a list of span tags on keyup.

I've created something only it returns strange values...

https://jsfiddle.net/5u373deu/1/

```
 function searchClients() {
   var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
   var s = clientSearch.value;
   $('.select-options span:not(:contains("' + s + '"))').hide();
 }

 $("#clientSearch").keyup(function() {
   searchClients();
 });
```

Comment: Try show all elements before hide.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5u373deu/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery KeyUp Live Search. How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507315/jquery-keyup-live-search-how-to)

Comment: What about [datalist](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/datalist)?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it become case sensitive, you need to override your current `contains`

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, index, obj) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(obj[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
function searchClients() {
   var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
   var s = clientSearch.value;
   $('.select-options span').show();
   $('.select-options span:not(:contains("' + s + '"))').hide();
 }

 $("#clientSearch").keyup(function() {
   searchClients();
 });
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-options ps-container below ps-active-y">

  <input id="clientSearch" type="text">

<span>Bitcoin</span><span>Cat</span><span>Whiskey</span><span>Table</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try refreshing your display everytime :

Note that your search is **case sensitive**.

```js
function searchClients() {
   var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
   var s = clientSearch.value;
   $('.select-options span').show();
   $('.select-options span:not(:contains("' + s + '"))').hide();
 }

 $("#clientSearch").keyup(function() {
   searchClients();
 });
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-options ps-container below ps-active-y">

  <input id="clientSearch" type="text">

<span>Bitcoin</span><span>Cat</span><span>Whiskey</span><span>Table</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/5u373deu/6/

The problem was with the fact that you were not showing all elements when the user cleared the filter text.

```
 function searchClients() {
   var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
   var s = clientSearch.value;
   $('.select-options span').show();
   $('.select-options span:not(:contains("'+s+'"))').hide();
 }

$("#clientSearch").keyup(function() {
  searchClients();
});
```

Comment: this is wrong. you should show all the spans before hide it to refresh it each time, rather than using `if.. else..`

Comment: Oh great thanks for the explanation! How would I go about making this work for capitalisation in words?

Comment: @Liam you should check out this article for case insensitive search: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/